# Java.SQL and PostgreSQL table

Tags: java, sql, database, postgresql, jdbc

I had a few questions for `java.sql.*`;

1)  How can I get a list of types for all columns in the table? Now I do request

```
SELECT data_type FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE  information_schema.columns.table_name = 'TableName';
```

How to do the same thing using Java? I think with the names of speakers, will be similar.

2)  Yet it is not clear how to define the column attributes: `NULL / NOT NULL`, `PRIMARY KEY`, etc.

3)  A separate question about `SERIAL`: when getting type, this column returns `INT` and its processing is not possible. Is there a method to distinguish a `SERIAL` column?

Thank you for your understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`DatabaseMetaData.getColumns()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getColumns%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) to query the columns in a table.

Based on your desire to get data on `TableName`:

```
DatabaseMetaData dbmd = connection.getMetaData()
try (ResultSet columns = dbmd.getColumns(null, null, "TableName", "%")) {
    while(columns.next()) {
        // get the info from the resultset (eg the java.sql.Types value):
        int dataType = columns.getInt("DATA_TYPE");
    }
}
```

The parameters to `getColumns` are `LIKE`-patterns, that is why the last parameter (`columnPattern`) gets the value `"%"`. The nullability can be retrieved from the columns `NULLABLE` and `IS_NULLABLE`, information on serial can probably be retrieved from the column `IS_AUTOINCREMENT`, see the documentation for details. For finding primary keys, you can use [`DatabaseMetaData.getPrimaryKeys()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getPrimaryKeys%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29).

For more information, look at the javadoc, it is very detailed.

Comment: bout NULLABLE / IS_NULLABLE and IS_AUTOINCREMENT for PostgreSQL is not true for the rest thanks.

Comment: Looking at the postgresql-jdbc sources for [AbstractJdbc2DatabaseMetaData](https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/blob/master/org/postgresql/jdbc2/AbstractJdbc2DatabaseMetaData.java) those columns are being set in the JDBC driver (line 2512 and 2519). It looks like `serial` is also indicated by column `TYPE_NAME` (line 2841)